# Transform mysql Subquery to Left Join

Tags: mysql

suppose I have the following table:

```
    id  parent
    1   1
    2   1
    3   1
    4   1
    5   2
    6   5
    7   5
```

And I want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT id_table.parent,id_table.count_id 
FROM 
    (SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item group by parent) AS id_table
     WHERE id_table.count_id = 
         (SELECT max(count_id) AS max_count_id FROM
                      ( SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent
                            FROM item group by parent ) AS id_table2 )
```

to get the following result:

```
parent  count_id    
1       4
```

I try to transform the query to optimize performance:

```
SELECT id_table.parent,id_table.count_id FROM
      (SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item GROUP BY parent)
              AS id_table    
LEFT JOIN

      (SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item GROUP BY parent )
              AS id_table2    
ON id_table.parent=id_table2.parent AND id_table.count_id<id_table2.count_id

WHERE id_table2.parent IS NULL
```

BUT got the following result instead, which I don't want:

```
parent  count_id    
1       4
2       1   
5       2
```

This is [my reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Could anyone tell me where I did wrong? 
regards

Comment: Why do you think left join will make it better instead of the one you already have ? Did you check the `explain select..` of your query ? What are the indexes available for the tables ? These needs to be checked first with the existing query before switching for a different query plan.

Comment: good point, let me do that just yet

Comment: Wait... I need the second query to work properly first in order to compare between those two... am I right?

Comment: can you explain in plain words what your query is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query does not work as you wish because it simply does not match any records in the join. Look:

You are declaring a join between a certain query and itself, according to the following condition:

```
ON id_table.parent=id_table2.parent AND id_table.count_id<id_table2.count_id
```

This means: select all the records from the first query (because it is a LEFT join), and *every record from the second query* which has the same `parent` and a `count` lower than the first query. ¡!

As you can see, this is absurd: Since the auto-joined query returns these records:

```
count_id parent
4        1
2        2
2        5
```

... the `parent` column is a *de-facto* PK. So. the pair (4,1) has no matching pairs (x,1) with x<4. (Idem the rest of the pairs.)

That was your mistake: The example from [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) is not appliable here, because in the `shop` table, surely there are more than one record with the same value of `article`, which is not your case of (`parent` has unique values in the auto-joined query).

The only query formula based on joins that comes to my mind is like this:

```
SELECT count_id, parent
FROM (SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item GROUP BY parent) query1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(query2.count_id) as max_id FROM (SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item GROUP BY parent) query2) queryMax ON query1.count_id=queryMax.max_id;
```

... but I doubt that such a complexity it will improve the performance of your first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output which you wanted to get i got a simpler solution. Maybe i didn't understand your question, but i'll give a shot.

Why to use your query (kinda long and messy) :

```
SELECT id_table.parent,id_table.count_id 
FROM 
(SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent FROM item group by parent) AS id_table
 WHERE id_table.count_id = 
     (SELECT max(count_id) AS max_count_id FROM
                  ( SELECT count(id) AS count_id,parent
                        FROM item group by parent ) AS id_table2 )
```

I acomplished the same result with much more simpler query.

```
SELECT parent, count(id) as count_id FROM items GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: hello, I tried to accomplish the query using JOIN based on the assumption it has more optimum result than using subquery or ORDER BY LIMIT 1. The question is answered properly by Little Santi

Answer (score -1):

To get the following result.

```
parent  count_id    
1       4
```

Can you check this

```
SELECT parent,count(*) AS parent_count FROM parent group by parent
 ORDER BY parent_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Subin, I think u misunderstood the question. Im looking for the first result but got the second instead. I edited the question to avoid further misunderstanding. regards

Comment: Sorry.. for that , If you want get max(count), i have edited query, check pls.

Comment: Hello Subin, I tried to recreate the query with JOIN assuming it has better optimization than using ORDER BY LIMIT 1. It is answered correctly by Little Santi